# How to remove PHP mail from spam using Zoho

Tags: php, email

I am using the mail-tester webpage to test my subscription email and remove it from  being tagged as spam. One of the items on there is that they didn't find an MX record behind my domain for hostgator.com. I am currently using Zoho mail to send/receive emails and my php script uses a zoho mail address to send the emails. I am wondering what the best way to remove this issue. I tried adding an MX record on our webserver but it messed up our email for zoho where we couldn't send or receive emails. Right now it shows as priority 10,30,50 for the mx zoho servers. Is there a way in php to have zoho send the email rather than our host server?

Comment: Setup the DKIM and SPF, managing your own mail server is a pain, I offload mail to a 3rd party, for pittance per month, much easier.

Comment: Have you thought about using SMTP instead of phpmail?

Comment: Hi Ben, I am not sure how to set that up. Can you set that up with php code? I remeber seeing that while searching it was a little unclear to me